# HTML in Flex mobile project

Tags: html, apache-flex, flash-builder

I have flex mobile project, and i need to show HTML text in some view of project.
Any solution other than the following will be appreciated. Because following techniques fails if HTML is not well formatted.

1: TextArea.textFlow = TextFlowUtil.importFromString("html text goes here");

2: TextArea.textFlow = TextConverter.importToFlow("html text goes here", TextConverter.TEXT_FIELD_HTML_FORMAT);

Thanks, Asif.

Comment: If you're going to show html text, shouldn't it be formatted properly anyways?

Answer (score 1):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- mobile_text/HTMLTextView.mxml -->
<s:View xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
        xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" title="HTMLText View"
        creationComplete="initView()">
    <s:layout>
        <s:VerticalLayout/>
</s:layout>
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import spark.components.supportClasses.StyleableTextField;
            private function initView():void {
                StyleableTextField(ta1.textDisplay).htmlText = "TextArea <b>bold</b>￼<i>italic</i>.";
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
        <s:TextArea id="ta1" width="100%"/>
</s:View>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is generally considered bad practice to use the TLF Framework in mobile for performance reasons; and I am pretty sure that the TextConverter classes you are referencing are part of TLF.

That said, you do have a few options.  [Start by reading this documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/mobileapps/WS19f279b149e7481c-3c2dbaa612bb06a5ea2-8000.html) on Using HTML Text in Mobile Applications.  Here are a relevant passage:

> To use the htmlText property in mobile
>   text controls, access the property on
>   the [StyleableTextField](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/supportClasses/StyleableTextField.html) subcontrol.

I'm pretty sure that Both TextInput and TextArea use the StyleableTextField under the hood in their mobile skins.

Comment: StyleableTextField worked to some extent. If we have following two type of HTML it renders the first one properly but fails to render the second one. 1: "<p>Some text</p><p>new paragraph</p>" 2: "Some text<p>new paragraph</p>". Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How does it render? Is the source available? [I'm not sure] and have you stepped through that code?

Comment: The following code starts new paragraph from new line StyleableTextField(txtJournalDetail.textDisplay).htmlText = "<p>Some text</p><p>new paragraph</p>";
But the following code does not, it just show the text on same line like “Some text new paragraph”
StyleableTextField(txtJournalDetail.textDisplay).htmlText = "Some text<p>new paragraph</p>";

Answer (score 0):

You better can use a StageWebView object. StageWebView is a wrapper for the native WebView object. It uses the build-in browser to show HTML. You can also load strings like the folowing example shows:

```
import flash.media.StageWebView;

var webView = new StageWebView();  
webView.stage = this.stage;
webView.viewPort = new Rectangle( 0, 0, this.stage.stageWidth, 100 );
webView.loadString( 'Your HTML Here' );
```

That's it, cheers.